# Create a new jquery chained method

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, method-chaining

How do you write new chained methods in jQuery?  I have a very procedural style in my jQuery:

```
$("#SaveButton").click(function () {
    Foo($("#SubTotal"));
    Foo($("#TaxTotal"));
    Foo($("#Total"));
    Bar($("#SubTotal"));
    Bar($("#TaxTotal"));
    Bar($("#Total"));        
});
```

How do I create a .foo() method in jQuery so that I can then write:

```
$("#SaveButton").click(function () {
    $("#SubTotal,#TaxTotal,#Total").foo().bar();
});
```

And in a related point - is there an easy way (in Visual Studio, or Notepad++ or something else) to find and replace all `Foo($("#selector"));` with `$("#selector").foo();`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define custom jQuery functions in this way:

```
$.fn.foo = function(){
    //`this` is a jQuery object, referring to the matched elements (by selector)
    return this.each(function(index, element){
        //`this` inside this function refers to the DOM element
        var $this = $(this); //`this` is wrapped in a jQuery object.
    });
}
```

After this definition, every `$("...")` object will have a `foo` method.

If you're not sure whether the jQuery object is defined by a dollar, wrap your definiton in this function:

```
(function($){
    //Within this wrapper, $ is the jQuery namespace
    $.fn.foo = function(){
        //...
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that .. I can see how to handle when the selector returns one match, I just have to use `$(this).prop("x","y");` etc, but what do I do when the selector returns multiple matches?

Comment: When you say to wrap, do you mean the whole thing will be `$.fn.foo = (function($){ // etc })(jQuery);`?

Comment: Thanks got it now, will try that out.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you need to return $(this) at the end pf each function to make it chainable.

Use the function robw wrote and return $(this).