# Visual Studio 2010 advanced find and replace?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, replace

Related to this question: [Create a new jquery chained method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800355/create-a-new-jquery-chained-method), how do I do an advanced find and replace in Visual Studio (or even Notepad++ or something else) to find:

```
Foo($("selector"));
```

And replace with:

```
$("selector").foo();
```

This is because I've created a new jQuery chained method:

```
$("#SaveButton").click(function () {
    $("#SubTotal").foo();
    $("#TaxTotal").foo();
    $("#Total").foo();
});
```

To replace this

```
$("#SaveButton").click(function () {
    Foo($("#SubTotal"));
    Foo($("#TaxTotal"));
    Foo($("#Total"));
});
```

And now I need to find and replace all instances of the old method call with the new chained method.

Answer (score 0):

Use [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in the Find options of Find/Replace dialog.

Hope that helps.

NB: I run screaming madly at the mere notion of having a stab at your particular expression but it is really just a transform of a number of matches so should be doable.

Comment: Ah no that doesn't help - regular expressions are way beyond my limited abilities :)  I don't know how to do the matching part or the replacing part with regex.  But yes I agree it probably will require regex to do this.